# How to make a Record with union type as key not mandatory for all values?

Tags: typescript

In a typescript project, I have a closed string property in a type:

```js
type SubscriptionLevel = 'normal' | 'premium' | 'cancelled';
```

I want to create a map-like object that use this type as a key, but not mandatory for all values.

A very simple example is this:

```js
const badgeIcon : Record<SubscriptionLevel, string | undefined> = {
    'premium' : 'crown',
    'cancelled' : 'grayed',
}
```

I want, only for some of the values, to specify mapped values (here I get string but actual code will lead to rendering react component differently).

This code run at runtime but Typescript complains that `Property 'normal' is missing in type '{ premium: string; cancelled: string; }' but required in type 'Record<SubscriptionLevel, string | undefined>'.(2741)`.

I can fix the code by adding also the `normal` key:

```js
const badgeIcon : Record<SubscriptionLevel, string | undefined> = {
    'premium' : 'crown',
    'cancelled' : 'grayed',
    'normal': undefined
}
```

But this approach requires to be exhaustive, even if only few kays should have a values (my actual code has 10 keys, but only 2 have to be set).

So my question is: is there any simple way to create this map, with optional values?

Type safety is important, so I don't want to use 'string' as key, because it won't check for typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for built-in utility type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type SubscriptionLevel = 'normal' | 'premium' | 'cancelled';

const badgeIcon: Partial<Record<SubscriptionLevel, string | undefined>> = {
  premium: 'crown',
  cancelled: 'grayed',
};
```

Comment: I was overthinking, started to play with generics, and all this brain washing syntaxes. Your solution works like a charm, and it easy to read and understand. Thanks !

Comment: Side note, using partial makes the `| undefined` useless